# Como añadir un ID a un button

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber porque me sale este error, si estoy ejecutando bien el codigo

> Error : Cannot set Propety 'id'.

```js
document.querySelector('.woof_submit_search_form').id='y';
```

```css
button#y {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<button style="float: left;" class="button woof_submit_search_form" id="y">Filtro</button>
```

Comment: que navegador estas utilizando

Answer (score 2):

Querrás decir, seleccionar el button por id, para eso hay dos formas, utilizando el selector `document.getElementById()` o `document.querySelector()`, espero te sirva, ya que si quieres agregar un atributo a una etiqueta lo puedes hacer con `setAttribute()`, te dejo el ejemplo, agregue otra etiqueta button y le cambie la clase `button2` para fines prácticos, ya que si lo selecciono por la clase `button` traería un array de las etiquetas que tengan ese *clase* y tendría que recorrer o entrar por su índice, espero te sirva, cualquier duda hazla saber. :D

```js
var btn_id = document.querySelector('#y');

var btn_id2 = document.getElementById('y');

console.log(btn_id);

console.log(btn_id2);


var btn_crearID = document.querySelector('.button2');

btn_crearID.setAttribute('id','prueba');

console.log(btn_crearID);
```

```html
<button style="float: left;" class="button woof_submit_search_form" id="y">Filtro</button>

<button style="float: left;" class="button2 woof_submit_search_form" >prueba</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para asignar el valor de un atributo a un elemento HTML debes usar el método `setAttribute()`.

```js
document.querySelector('.woof_submit_search_form').setAttribute('id', 'myId')
```

```css
button#y {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button style="float: left;" class="button woof_submit_search_form" id="y">Filtro</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración